# Rotating Gradient In Figma By 90 Degrees So It Runs Exactly From 0 % to 100 %

Tags: gradient, figma

How can I rotate a gradient in Figma exactly around 90 degs, running from 0 % to 100 %?  This is how the gradient initially looks like, running exactly from the top of the group to the bottom:

[image]

Now when I rotate it around 90 degrees by hand, I have to adjust the handle by hand:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rqm3G.jpg

It looks alrightish, but it bugs that I cannot just enter somewhere the number 90 and have the new gradient running exactly from left to right, without having to eyeball anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to eyeball the angle.  Hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> as you click and drag a gradient handle. This will constrain the rotation to multiples of 45°

An example

[image]

Comment: Yes, so I don't have to eyeball the angle, but I have to eyeballe the start and stop of the gradient.  I want to go exactly from 0 % to 100 %.

Comment: @fweth - you could use some guides to help you line things up.  There is no way (as far as I know) of doing what you want by entering in a number. That would likely involve reprogramming the software. I'm trying to give you a practical answer here that is actually possible.

Comment: Thanks!  Yeah, I think Boxy SVG might serve my purpose better than Figma, as they allow you to directly mess with the SVG code, which in this case is easier than doing it in Figma.

Comment: @tweth If you want to mess with the SVG code, then Inkscape is also a fully fledged SVG editor, plus it's opensource and free. There's an XML editor built in., where you can actually input the numerical X and Y co-ordinates of the start and end points of a gradient in the XML editor. You can also use a plain text editor to edit SVGs.